# Relate solutions to quadratic eqs.

Tags: calculus, quadratics, quadratic-forms

I have two quadratic eqs:
\begin{align}
\frac1{x} & = 2 + \frac1{1-r} + \frac1{1-x}\\
\frac1{y} & = 2 - \frac1{r} + \frac1{1-y},
\end{align}
where $r\in(0,1)$ is a parameter.

I am interested either in a nice relation between $x,y$ that solve each of the equations and satisfy $x,y\in(0,1)$ or any interesting observation on the equations.